# connecting remote mysql database using IP address of the remote system in android emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is the following code:

```
 `package com.tom.jam;

//import java.sql.Connection;
//import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.*;
import android.app.Activity;
//import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MyserverActivity extends Activity {
TextView mf,ct;
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mf=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.myfield);
    ct=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cont);
        Connection con = null;

        try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.100/test","root", "secret");
          if(!con.isClosed())
          {

              Statement st = con.createStatement();
              ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from ram");
              while(rs.next())
              {
              ct.setText("ID" + rs.getString(1) + "Name " + rs.getString(2));
              }

            mf.setText("Successfully connected to " +
              "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");

          }
        } catch(Exception e) {
          mf.setText("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
          try {
            if(con != null)
              con.close();
          }catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
}
}`
```

we have set the following permissions in

```
manifest:android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
         android.permission.INTERNET,
         android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

NO errors and warnings but while running emulator is showing the following exception:

```
 Unable to connect to any hosts due to exception:java.net.SocketTimeoutException:Connection timed out.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: we are doing chatting application in android 2.3.3 and want to establish connection between a server and multiple clients.We want to create a network between two emulators present in two different systems and send messages in between them,  When i tried with the above code for accessing the database of the server the following issue is coming. Any help in this regard will be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.net.SocketTimeoutException:Connection timed out, exception occurs when destination system is not reachable. It may be due to proxy not set on your emulator, to set proxy on emulator you can start emulator by command in command prompt:

```
emulator -avd avdname -http-proxy http://192.168.1.1:8080
```

Here replace avdname to name of avd you want to run your program, and http:192.168.1.1 to your proxy server.

Comment: We tried what you suggested but getting the following error in cmd prompt:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools>emulator -avd star -http-proxy
http://192.168.1.1:8080

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools>emulator: WARNING: Unable to cr
eate sensors port: Unknown error
emulator: Could not connect to proxy at 192.168.1.1:8080: resource temporarily u
navailable !
emulator: Proxy will be ignored !

Comment: you need to add proxy address by argunment http://192.168.1.1:8080 instead of 192.168.1.1:8080

Comment: Thank you for the feed back, where to pass the argument and can we use any other port number than 8080 and which IP address we should provide here IP of server or client?

Comment: its ip of server and you are providing ip of proxy server, your device is connecting with, not destimation server.

Comment: we have only 1 server and no proxy server.Sorry if my question so noobish.Android is completely new to us. Please clarify your answer little more

Comment: proxy server is the server, by which your computer is connected to internet, please check with your system admin, or see in your browser settings on your computer.