# I cannot connect to my remote MySQL via Android SDK

Tags: java, android, mysql, eclipse

I have two similar program. the First: *Java for PC*, the Second: *Android*. I have a MacOS Pro Server with ip 192.168.0.103 in my local network. MacOS Server has got MySQL-Server 5.0.1, with

```
CREATE DATABASE db_demo01;
CREATE USER 'user01'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '1234567';
GRANT ALL ON db_demo01.* TO 'user01'@'%';
```

My PC App has following code:

```
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.103:3306/";
            String dbName = "db_demo01";
            String userName = "user01";
            String userPass = "1234567";

            try
            {
                Class.forName(driver);
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,userPass);
                System.out.println("Connected!");
                conn.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Error:" + ex.getMessage());
            }
```

It's work!But when I try to do this with my android app, I'v got connection fail. I don't know why... I posted the full code of my app below:

```
package com.navi.newser;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    /// VARIABLES
    private TextView textWidget;
    private TableLayout tableWidget;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CreateOnClickConnect(); 
    }

    private void CreateOnClickConnect()
    {
        textWidget = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tableWidget = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table1);
        Button cmd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        cmd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ConnectToMySQL();
            }
        });
    }

    private class Connect extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
         {
            String response = "";

            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.103:3306/";
            String dbName = "db_demo01";
            String userName = "user01";
            String userPass = "1234567";
            Connection conn = null;
            try
            {
                Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,userPass);
                response += "Connected!";
                Log.e("MySQL", response);
                conn.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                response += "Error:" + ex.getMessage();
                Log.e("MySQL", response);
            }
            publishProgress("Almost...");
            return response;
         }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            textWidget.setText(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
            textWidget.setText(text[0]);
        }
    }

    public void ConnectToMySQL()
    {
        new Connect().execute();
    }
```

[image]

I use Eclipse Luna.

```
01-20 19:09:07.777: E/dalvikvm(1069): Could not find class 'javax.naming.StringRefAddr', referenced from method com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty.storeTo
```

I don't have other errors.

Comment: I would suggest you check for mysql settings, primarily for "bind" address, if your server is listening only on localhost, then it will not accept connections from different IP, althoug i dont know if the Android Emulator has it's own IP

Answer (score 0):

The emulator is always isolated from your machine's network, take a look at this [Network Address Space](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Answer (score 0):

Start your emulator with this

`emulator -avd avdname -http-proxy http://192.168.0.1:8080`

Here replace avdname to name of avd you want to run your program, and http:192.168.1.1 to your proxy server.

[original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9171446/2970351)

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to make some settings; first of all with emulator isn't always a good idea to use it, while there is internet connection in the middle. Also the library (jar) for the connector should be in a folder called lib in Android project. For MySQL interaction, I use JSON with PHP. I hope this help you !